# Discriminatory treatment of elements' sizes by browser print functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, printing

I'm creating a webpage on which a user can edit the content of the 'printable area'. I have placed an element on the page, which corresponds perfectly in size to the 'printable area'. In the picture below, the 'printable area' is represented by the `div` with the white background.

[image: printable-area]

If you resize the window by opening the console (or even shrinking the size of the browser itself), the 'printable area' also shrinks and so too does the `div` which represents the 'printable area', as can be seen in the following image.

[image: printable-area-is-responsive]

However, the issue that I'm encountering is that the 'printable area', its corresponding `div`, and other elements scale responsively with the browser, whereas text not only does not scale responsively, but, if you manually change the `font-size` of any text so that it **appears** to scale responsively, the printer/print preview recognizes that change in size and only that change; so that if you were to print the document now, the text would be much smaller in relation to all of the other elements, as shown in the images below.

[**It's not letting me post the one other image...**]

[image]
[image]

Obviously one solution would be to store the original `font-size` (the `font-size` which corresponds to the 'printable area' in a 1:1 ratio when the browser is maximized) and use that for printing, but scale the text as the browser/document is scaled.

I'm wondering whether or not there are any better solutions?! Why does the browser print functionality treat the size of the text differently than non-textual elements?

**To clarify, what I'm trying to do and will be doing is scaling the text with the document, so that the text is always 1:1 in size with the document *as it is displayed* and *as it is printed.***

Comment: What units are you using to set your font size?

Comment: You seem to believe changing `font-size` based on device width has something to do with responsiveness. It doesn't. Responsiveness is the property/attribute/ability of a web page to remain usable and readable on all devices, meaning, among others, it should re-flow its contents, keeping text size within reasonable, readable, limits. What you seem to want is scaling, which has nothing to do with responsiveness.If you want to scale font size based on device width use `vw` as unit, but that's really ***anti-responsive***.

Comment: @jmargolisvt well, i'm going to be using `rem` and then scaling the `font-size` of `:root`. to be clear, the issue isn't that the text does not scale, the issue is that if you manually scale the text, that change is reflected in the print and is non-responsive, whereas all of the other elements are. in other words, when you print all non-textual elements act responsively and text obviously does not

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you're misunderstanding the question. the issue i'm having has nothing to do with the scaling of text. the real issue is about how a browser's print functionality treats non-textual elements differently than it deals with changes to text size... it treats non-textual elements responsively, whereas the same is not true of text

Comment: Not having specific `@print` styles allows browsers to implement their own `@print` rules which are aimed at readability, removing backgrounds, changing font colors and/or sizes within limits deemed "decent". Regardless, I don't think anyone can be of much help without a [mcve]. You need to provide a lot more details, such as list of browsers you tested this in or list of browsers you aim this at, as you shouldn't expect two different browsers to print this exactly the same. Even when you do specify `@print` rules differences can be quite big.